# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '@hotwired/turbo-rails'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-rails, shakapacker

I am using the Shakapacker https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails and I have come across this error despite following all the steps in the Get started with shakapacker section I am not sure why this is happening any help is appreciated

config/importmap.rb

```
# Pin npm packages by running ./bin/importmap

pin "application", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
```

app/javascript/application.js

```
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails" 
import "controllers"
```

picture of error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing concepts. `Shakapacker` and `Import Maps` are 2 different ways of building your front-end.

- [Shakapacker](https://github.com/shakacode/shakapacker): it's based on webpack, so you are running a Node.js bundler with a compilation/transpilation step. Dependencies are defined in the `package.json`.
- [Import Maps](https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails): based on ESM so it runs directly in the browser with no bundling step. It's the new Rails 7+ default.

So first of all, you'll need to choose one of the options to build your front-end code (you can probably mix both, but it will be messy if you don't have a clear understanding of how they work). If you just need "Hotwire" and don't want any kind of complex stuff (three-shaking, hot-reloading, ...), the `importmap-rails` solution is simpler and the recommended way to go.

There is also a 3rd option (my ‍♂️ preferred one): [jsbundling-rails](https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails). It's a small layer/glue-code to use a js bundler (esbuild, webpack or rollup) and rely on the Rails assets pipeline (Sprockets) to plug-in into the app. I you want to see an example of this, some time ago I published a ready-to-go template: https://github.com/ralixjs/rails-ralix-tailwind.

Comment: Wow, this is super useful. I'm making the same mistake. How do I know which of the 2 concepts is winning in my repo? Is there a config point where it says: use importmaps vs use shakapacker?